# ARG - morse/wordplay puzzle?

Tags: wordplay, visual, steganography

There's a (likely) fan made ARG* we've been trying to solve for the past few days. This is the clue/puzzle:

[image]

The answer is presumably a word or a number, but it apparently should be self evident as an answer. It is highly likely a 4 digit number, as all previous answers were 4 digit numbers.
It may or may not have "?" at the beginning. "ninth" as an answer does not work.

The morse code (**paraphrased**) states:

Your teamwork so far has been amazing the next clue is hidden in this message good luck (paraphrased, the original text has weird spacing)

The original (following natural morse where "/" is a word break):

Your teamworkso farhas beenamazingthe next clueis hidden inthis messagegood luck.

Note that the single word phrases (teamworkso) has a natural linebreak in the original image. The interesting part is that only "farhas" doesn't have a line break nor a slash.

A hint was given through chat. (The previous answers in the ARG were numbers, so perhaps puzzle maker just want to look at numbers again)

[image]

*The ARG is for the game 'Death Stranding' by Hideo Kojima. [Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbGD_d2cGEk)

The 'answers' are submittable through [discord](https://discordapp.com/channels/389286357274460171/390038913030291458) as bot commands (i.e. `?answer`).

The context/references might be important, but from the puzzle maker's description (from chat) it is apparently all "in the message". However, it might be helpful to have an idea on what the ARG's context is.

Comment: Welcome to puzzling! Make sure to take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour). If the original text has weird spacing, that is most likely part of the puzzle. It would make the puzzle easier for us to solve if you can reproduce the original text exactly.

Comment: Thanks @micsthepick! I tried to clarify as much as possible the actual/original morse translation

Comment: This puzzle seems to come from some external source. Can you attribute that reference, and confirm that this is not for an on-going contest or something similar?

Comment: @Lolgast I added some context in the post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer could be

> 65/758, or possibly just 65758

because

> One line of code in the image is bolder than the others. That line has the Morse code for the words ***this message*** and we are told "the next clue is hidden in this message."
>
> All digits in Morse code use combinations of exactly five dots and dashes. Slightly incredibly, we can rewrite the line in groups of five, all of which are valid digits:
>
>  `-.... ..... / --... ..... ---..`
>
>  which decodes to 65/758. It isn't clear whether we should remove the / character to get just 65758.

Comment: This incredibly turned out to be the answer. The single clue is the "hidden" (hidden in this message) slash (farhas). Adding 65, 67 (6 was morse from farhas), 58 results in 190, and the command leads to the next step (http://32-34-17-28-26-26-27.tumblr.com). We've been stuck for this for hours and you saw it in nine hours, help us solve the next one ;)

Comment: the answer itself was fourthousandsevenhundredthirtyfour (190 + previous answer in the puzzle)

Comment: *not stuck for hours, we've been stuck on it for three days (apologies for the b2b comments, I can't edit them!)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe partial answer

> The first letters of the words that follow another word without a space are shatitg. You can make these words from it: A Tights, Hag Tits, Hags Tit, Shag Tit, Gash Tit, Ghats Ti, Ghats It,Ghat Tis,Ghat Its,Ghat Sit,Stag Hit,Tags Hit,Tag Shit,Tag Hist,Tag Hits,Tag This,Hat Gist,As Tight,At Sight,Tat Sigh

Because we see a baby in the background

> maybe it has something to do with tits?

Comment: So that just made me laugh

Comment: This generated lots of laugh in chat but unfortunately was not the answer (I thought it was -- damn!)

Perhaps it is a partial answer though!